# Laravel Eloquent select (firstornew / firstorcreate / firstorupdate) does not seem to work within package

Tags: php, laravel, package, eloquent

I have been unsuccessfully trying to update database records within a package (my first) I am trying to develop. It's a file upload script and it is suppose to upload the file to a directory, save its path, the name given to it by the user and the set of tags assigned to a database. Insert works perfectly. However, when the file is updated with new tags (same name) it just gives me a blank response. My implementation is as below:

```
$filename = Input::get('filename') . '.' . Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$tags = Input::get('tags');

$doc = Document::firstOrNew(array('filename' => $filename));
$doc->tags = $tags;
$saved = $doc->save();
```

Document model is as below:

```
class Document extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'documents';
    protected $softDelete = true;
    protected $fillable = array('filename');

    public function __construct($attributes = array()) {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why would "selects" not work while insert works perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought I would answer just to be tidy. Looks like you are missing the relationship definition in your model:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\YourTagsModel');
}
```

Also in turn, your tags model should have the opposite definition:

```
public function document()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\YourDocumentModel');
}
```